# Change primary key type from int to bigint

Tags: sql-server-2008, primary-key, bigint

I have some tables in my database that have primary keys of type int that I'd like to change to type bigint.  What's the best strategy to accomplish this without dropping/recreating tables and constraints?

These primary keys are being used as foreign keys in other tables, so that will factor in.

Comment: Do u need more help for this query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In, SSMS, execute bellow steps.

> 1. Click Tools.
> 2. Select Options
> 3. Select Designer

Just uncheck the Option highlighted in the Screenshot. Now you can use the `Alter script` to change the `DDL`.

[image]

Comment: To be clear the script generated **will** drop/recreate tables and constraints.

Comment: @MartinSmith - sir, I just want to stop the message to prevent user to change schema. I am suggesting this without drop/recreate.

Comment: The script it generates will rebuild the table behind the scenes though. It might not be a bad starting point though.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Sir,  Data will be preserved without any loss and no harm to schema. We can go with it .